# Code to extract center curve (medial axis or topological skeleton) of a mesh or point cloud?

Tags: c#, python, vb.net, computational-geometry, mesh

Would you know any existing code to extract the center curve of a mesh or a point cloud? 
The center curve of a mesh is equidistant to its [boundaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29).

I looked at several questions/answers posted already such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069523/find-medial-axis-of-a-polygon-using-c-sharp) on a planar polygon but could not find one that explains results in 3D such as the one shown in this [paper](http://code.google.com/p/skeletonization/) and this [one](http://visgraph.cse.ust.hk/projects/skeleton/) on "point cloud skeletonization through Laplacian-Based Contraction" where this quadratic [equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147136/what-is-the-lvert-symbol) comes back in both.

There is also the approach described in this [paper](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/1820-0214/2010/1820-02141001063S.pdf) on 3D Mesh Skeleton Extraction using prominent Segmentation based on "connecting rings".

So far the closest i got to making it work is the [Skeletonize3D](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=plugin:morphology:skeletonize3d:start) plugin for ImageJ but I could not make it works for an .obj mesh yet.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? ["Cocone Software for surface reconstruction and medial axis"](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~tamaldey/cocone.html) - "_In addition to the  surface, Tight Cocone below can compute an approximate  medial axis or MAT of the object._"

Comment: Thank you @bobobobo but it only gives a [mesh](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~tamaldey/medialaxis_pointcloud.htm) as an output when I need a curve.

Comment: You want to reduce a point cloud in 3D to a single curve, correct?  What properties do you want the curve to satisfy?  There is not a unique such curve, so I think you need to specify in more detail what it is you seek.

Comment: Thank you @JosephO'Rourke, this is correct. The curve I am looking for is the center curve of the mesh which is equidistant to its boundaries. Does that help? I updated the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in general such a curve does not exist.  It only exists under very special circumstances, for example, if the boundary of your cloud can be generated by sweeping a sphere along a curve, e.g., this shape produced in POVRay (from [this web page](http://www.f-lohmueller.de/pov_tut/all_shapes/shapes630e.htm)):

          [image: Swept Sphere]
So you will have to accept some type of approximation.

One idea is to first, compute the boundary somehow.  Since you mention mesh, maybe you already have the boundary.  Second, find maximal inscribed spheres.  Third, approximate their centers by a best-fit curve.

As *bo*^4 suggests, and your title acknowledges, you are really looking for the [medial axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis), which is both difficult to compute and in general a multisheeted surface.  Essentially you want to approximate the medial axis by a single curve.